# Multiple API data sent to blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to send 3 API data to blade.

```php
$data['dataList'] = Http::get(Config::get('apis.section.readAll'))->json();

$company['companyList'] = Http::get(Config::get('apis.company.readAll'))->json();

$department['departmentList'] = Http::get(Config::get('apis.department.readAll'))->json();

return view('section.section', $data, $department, $company);
```

In this way I can't access company data, but first two variables can be accessed.

```
return view('section.section', compact('data', 'department', 'company'));
```

In this way, when I loop through each variable:

```
@foreach($company['companyList'] as $com)
    @foreach($com as $k => $comp)
        <option value="{{ $comp['company_id'] }}">{{ $comp['comp_name'] }}</option>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

It shows the following error: `Illegal string offset 'company_id'`.

Comment: Check the output of `dd($company['companyList'])` that it contains `company_id` or not.

Comment: It doesn't. Solved it by changing variable names.

Comment: $data['dataList']=Http::get(Config::get('apis.section.readAll'))->json();
$data['companyList']=Http::get(Config::get('apis.company.readAll'))->json();
$data['departmentList']=Http::get(Config::get('apis.department.readAll'))->json();
return view('section.section', $data);

Comment: This solved the issue.